# Node JS Multiple Server Instances, one for each core?

Tags: node.js, pm2, cpu-cores

So correct me if any part of this is wrong but this is my understanding and hope. As far as I know an instance of Node will run on 1 CPU core. So I have an API and a UI, both 100% stateless, so in I had an idea to use PM2 to spawn 10 or 20 processes on my server (84 core server). Each process running a copy of the API and then create a small node application that will forward traffic between each instance.

This should in theory let me scale my application pretty well, am I thinking of this incorrectly? Is it possible to setup Node Js in this way? Am I thinking of this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you can**

One instance of node process takes one core. So if have 2 cores you should ideally run 2 `pm2 clusters`. As you said, you have 84 cores then you can easily run 20 processes using below command.

```
pm2 start -i 20 app.js
```

You application can horizontally scale in this way. However if you have multiple machines where you want have the same setup. You will need `nginx` for load balancing.

Comment: Are you inferring that PM2 clusters already does what I want it to do and that I wont have to make a small node js instance that routes the traffic between my instances?

Comment: @CMOS yes. pm2 cluster will do the job for you